# Mysql not yet running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, whatsapp

I am trying to use whatsapp business api. But the problem is when I run docker-compose up I get the error Mysql not yet started. Though the wadebug tool shows everything correct. I am not able to hit any api 
eg GET https://localhost:9090/v1/settings/application I am getting connection refused in this request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5kWj.png)

I have also one more doubt.Am I hitting the right api or is there any different. In their documentation it is written your app hostname. Docker-compose ps shows 0.0.0.0:9000->443. So is it right?

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
   version: '3'

volumes:
  whatsappMedia:
    driver: local
  mysqlData:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: hello123
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: hello123
    expose:
        - "33060"
    ports:
        - "33060:3306"
    volumes:
     - mysqlData:/var/lib/mysql
    network_mode: bridge
  wacore:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.25.1 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    network_mode: bridge
    links:
      - db
  waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.25.1 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    ports:
     - "9090:443"
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "wacore"
    links:
      - db
      - wacore
    network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: You have some Docker Compose file that you run and get problems. But we don't have your Docker Compose file and we cannot know why you have problems.

Comment: Check whether the db service is running using `docker-compose ps`. Could you also run `docker-compose logs -f` so we can see what is going on (or paste the output from `docker-compose up`.

Comment: db service is running @leeman24

Comment: added the file @nickolay.laptev

Comment: I want to see the mysql (db) logs. Or you can do a test to connect to mysql from your host machine to ensure it is actually running. My guess is that the issue is with your other whatsapp services configuration.

Comment: I assume `db.env` contains the connection string for mysql. Ensure it is using `db` as the host name (not localhost) as well as the user/password you specified. Testing the connection first would be a good idea.

Comment: oh thanks I was making it localhost now its not getting that error . One more thing now want to ask I am using windows so what should I specify in volume directory. It gives me error requirement string @leeman24

Comment: It is showing chat service started @leeman24. But still can't hit any api. What to do now. I am new in docker and this stuff.

Comment: With regards to the volume, I think what you have there may be valid (although you may have to put quotes around it) which is called a named volume that will be managed by docker and can view with `docker volume ls`. I am not the biggest fan of those as I like to easily see the files that are mounted so what i'd suggest for you (so you don't get tripped up on syntax) is to use something like `- ./data:/path/to/data`. If you need to specify full path,use `c:/myfolder:/path/to/data". Also Docker for Windows requires you to share the drive if you mount a volume so look in settings > shared drive.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help you debug the chat service as I am only familiar with docker/docker-compose and various db's. You will need to troubleshoot that yourself. You should always start with `docker-compose logs -f` and follow the errors.

Comment: thanks @leeman24 for helping these things. But I still can't hit the api to get any reponse. I saw the logs it said service started. Can't find the error

Comment: I'm assuming your Docker-compose ps shows 0.0.0.0:9090->443 and not 0.0.0.0:9000->443. 
Can you try running https://localhost:9090/v1/health and see if you get anything